# How do I install Flash for just one browser on Mac?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, browser-addons, flash

How can I install Adobe Flash for just Firefox and not Safari? I would like to have Flash not load at all in Safari, so the Click to Flash extension is not the solution I want. I've looked at the Safari plist and don't see any way to disable plugins in it.

Answer (score 4):

Since both Firefox and Safari use the system-wide installation of Flash, I don't think this is doable. However: Chrome uses it's own Flash-bundle. If you uninstall flash on your system, and then use Chrome to view Flash-sites, it would not be loaded at all in Safari, and work fine in Chrome.

See Gruber's [post](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/flash_free_and_cheating_with_google_chrome) on this for more info.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing. I really only need flash for speedtest.net and Google voice, but speedtest.net now only gives me an error in Chrome that my version of Flash is too old. Alternatively, updating the Flash plugin that is built into Chrome would solve this for me. I found the way to force Chrome to ignore it's built in plugins in this Adobe KB article http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/839/cpsid_83950.html, but then Chrome just uses the plugin installed for the system.

Comment: I had reinstalled Chrome, trahed it's pref file, and cleared all browsing data and it and was still unable to access speedtest. Turns out this was not a version problem with Flash as the error on speedtest indicated, as clearing my flash cookies fixed it. I'll leave this question here as I would like to know if installing a plugin for one browser is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Firefox.

- Install Flash from [the Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer.html).
- Install [Flashlight add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashlight-1/) for Firefox.
- Check "Save current Flash Player" in Flashlight's toolbar.
- Uninstall the Flash plugin from the system.
- Open Firefox and click the Flashlight toolbar » Flash Players » "Name of the Flash plugin".

Now you have Firefox with Flash and a clean Safari.